# How to make Visual Studio 2013 Errors show in english

Tags: .net, visual-studio, localization, visual-studio-2013

I learn ASP .NET and if error occures I have to translate it for stackoverflow. For instance:

```
Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60451 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
```

How to switch language from partially polish-english to english. The Visual Studio 2013 is completely in english besides that.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an error string that Visual Studio generated.  This came from [IErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a COM interface to document an HRESULT code.  0x800a139e in your case.

Clearly your browser is convinced that Polish is still your mother-tongue.  You ought to ask at superuser.com how to tell it otherwise.  In all likelihood that *does* require running the English version of Windows.  Ultimate supports downloadable language packs that permit you changing the system language on the fly.  Well, flyish, they are half a gigabyte each and require a logout + login to make a change effective.

Comment: One clarifying point to add: some of the errors come from Visual Studio, and some of them (or parts of them in this case) come from the .NET runtime.  The runtime is using the OS language settings, whereas VS has been set to use English.  Hence the mixup.