# Changing Exception names to English

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

After being forced to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7, my exception names are shown in my native language (Danish). Before upgrading my system/Windows 7 language was Danish too, but exceptions was in English.

How do I change the system to show me the exception names in English again?

UPDATE

Webruster below was right. It was caused by the .NET language pack. But unfortunately my program is depending on it. My own rough solution was to place the following code before the line causing the exception:

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but this could be some kind of general .Net setting...

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352827/how-to-make-visual-studio-2013-errors-show-in-english

Comment: do you have any .net framework language packs installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework comes in two parts:

1. The .NET framework itself
2. The .NET framework language packs

All texts (ex. exception messages, button labels on a MessageBox, etc.) are in English in the .NET framework itself. The language packs have the localized texts.

Depending on your exact situation, a solution would be to uninstall the language packs (i.e. tell the client to do so). In that case, the exception texts will be in English. Note however, that all other framework-supplied text will be English as well (ex. the button labels on a MessageBox, keyboard shortcuts for ApplicationCommands).

**Note**:With every update of the .NET Framework via Windows Update, the language pack is installed again